# permissions for Lua Scripts in C

Tags: linux, lua, permissions

Is it possible to give the lua script lower permissions so that it is not possible to execute OS functions ?

for example:
`os.execute("mkdir ..")`

I use the lua 5.3.5 library. Maybe it includes an option to allow or disallow some lua functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, typically `Lua` initialization load all the standard library:

```
lua_State *LuaState = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(LuaState);
```

But you could adjust to include just what you need with the functions from `lualib.h`:

```
luaopen_package
luaopen_coroutine
luaopen_string
luaopen_utf8
luaopen_table
luaopen_math
luaopen_io
luaopen_os
luaopen_debug
```

In such case you could have the following initialization:

```
lua_State *LuaState = luaL_newstate();
luaopen_io(LuaState);
luaopen_table(LuaState);
luaopen_string(LuaState);
```

You can find more details in the chapter 6 of the documentation

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6

Answer (score 2):

If you use `luaL_openlibs` to load Lua's standard libraries, just copy `linit.c` to your project and edit it to choose the libraries you want to export.

If you want to remove only a few functions, do this after loading the libraries:

```
luaL_dostring(L,"os.execute=nil");
```